# using AJAX results variable throughout code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube-api

I'm using jQuery AJAX to get an array from a PHP file which is getting data from a MySQL database. I'm now trying to use that array outside my ajax call. Specifically I'm loading multiple videoIDs for YT.Player but I'm stumbling on getting my array to another function.

Here's my testing code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    var data = new Array();
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
  url: 'test.php',
  data: 'id=testdata',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
    data = result;
    $('#div1').html(result[4]);
  },
  });
});
$("button").click(function(){
  alert(data[4]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<button id="button">Test</button>
<div id="div1"><h2>div1</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The div changes a half second after the page loads as expected. The click function for testing doesn't work, and its not working in the real function I'm working on:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) { 
        ++i;
        player.loadVideoById(data[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my first project with jQuery and JS so I'm hoping I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put

```
$("button").click(function(){
  alert(data[4]);
});
```

inside

```
$(document).ready( function() {

});
```

Also, if you put *var* before variable then it becomes local variable.

So, you should either remove *var* before

```
data = new Array();
```

or just put as a additional parameter

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event, data) {        
    if(event.data === 0) { 
        ++i;
        player.loadVideoById(data[i]);
    }
}
```

but then you also need to call it inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {} );
```

scope.